# Trouble creating user control in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, panel

I'm creating a user control in C# but I can't figure out how to do the event stuff. I want to change the backcolor property of the panel on mouse hover but it's not working.

**Code:**

```
public partial class QuestionList : UserControl
{
    public QuestionList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public struct QuestionListItem
    {
        public string Question { get; set; }
        public string Answer { get; set; }

        public QuestionListItem(string question, string answer)
        {
            Question = question;
            Answer = answer;
        }
    }

    public void Add(QuestionListItem questionlistItem)
    {
        Panel panel = new Panel();
        panel.Dock = DockStyle.Top;

        Label label = new Label();
        label.MouseHover += Label_MouseHover;
        label.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        label.Text = questionlistItem.Question;
        panel.Controls.Add(label);

        Controls.Add(panel);
    }

    //Here (no idea what I just did..)
    private void Label_MouseHover(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label label = (Label)sender;
        Panel panel = (Panel)label.Container;
        panel.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have added your event handler right. The problem is with the line you put in your event handler:

```
Panel panel = (Panel)label.Container;
```

Should be

```
Panel panel = (Panel)label.Parent;
```

Change the Container into Parent.

Also, I think it is best to use VS designer to test what is the strongly-typed signature of the event handler. In your signature, you use EventArgs. I believe it should be MouseEventArgs instead.

Comment: Oh my god thank you it works !! Have a great day :DD

Comment: Oh it's youu. I didn't check on my older thread until now, upvoted for the good logical answer. Thanks for the instant and useful help you give, you're a good person :))

Comment: @Tayab no problem. ^_^ thanks! that will save my day.